# How to extract specific text from a pdf using python?

Tags: python, image, ocr, python-tesseract, pdftotext

These are the items which are needed to be extracted from the pdf:

[image]

This is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jFfnWQ0uha0zfOn9lgX2N5jgWSfNr_is/view?usp=share_link) to the PDF.

Could anyone solve this problem using Python with proper comments to help me understand?

```
import pdf2image
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image = pdf2image.convert_from_path('/content/SRW1012022Y0002378_220216102321.PDF')
for pagenumber, page in enumerate(image):
    detected_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(page)
    print(detected_text)
```

I tried the above code snippet, and I can extract all the text from pdf, but I can't grab specific text to continue applying logic to it.

Comment: Do you know what specific text you want?

Comment: If you know that "specific" text, then what more do you want? The position of it on the page. Also don't understand why Tesseract is mentioned: Is it an image which first needs to be OCRed?

Comment: @KJ Could you write a code for the shipper address?

Comment: @NumanIjaz the details which are in the image are needed to be extracted from pdf file